# Bootstrap justify-content-around last item misplaced

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

Currently my prototype Website looks like this, with justify-content-around: 
[image]

What I would like is, that when there is an uneven amount of cards, that the last card is in line with the others. Is there a way to do it? I know, that it works with justify-space-between, but what about around?

Here's my source code:

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container-fluid row justify-content-around cards ml-0">
            <div class="card col-12 col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 mb-4 mx-1">
                <img src="../images/lit.svg" class="card-img-top" alt="alternative">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card col-12 col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 mb-4 mx-1">
                <img src="../images/lit.svg" class="card-img-top" alt="alternative">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card col-12 col-md-5 col-lg-4  col-xl-3 mb-4 mx-1">
                <img src="../images/lit.svg" class="card-img-top" alt="alternative">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

what I added in an extra css file is the following:

```
.cards::after{
    content: '';
    flex: auto;
}
```

So that at least the last item is on the left side and not in the middle!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `col-md-5` to `col-md-4` . Below I've done for one of your small snippet

```
    <div class="card col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 mb-4 mx-1">
        <img src="../images/lit.svg" class="card-img-top" alt="alternative">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```